# How can I reload web page in Zend forms

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am attempting to reload a webpage using Zend Framework Forms.  The first time the page is loaded it looks fine.  Then I click on an action in my webpage which looks like below:

```
     <a style="color:#FFF" href="/admin/showMedia/1" class="">Today </a>
```

When the logic is processed in my controller program, it returns the new data I want in the form but much of the form layout is lost.  Below is my controller logic:

```
     public function showmediaAction()
{
    $thistype = 0;
    $type = ( int )$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0)
    if(isset($type))
        $thistype = $type;  

    $d = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Mytable\Data\Db');

    $response = $d->getThisTable()->geTotalCount();
    $mediacount = $response;
    $todaycount = 0;
    $totalcount = 0;

    if($thistype == 1)
    {
    $todaycount = $this->getTodayCount($d);
    $count = count($todaycount);
    $i = 0;
    $totalcount = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $totalcount += $todaycount[$i];
    }
    }

    $this->viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $this->viewModel->setTemplate('mydir/admin/show-media.phtml');

    $this->viewModel->setVariables(array(
        'mediacount' => $mediacount,
        'todaycount' => $todaycount,
        'todaytotalcount' => (string)$totalcount
                ));
            return $this->viewModel;
           }
```

So why is my form not rendered properly the second time through this logic.  The first time the page loads, I display an alert.  When the above logic is performed the second time, the alert does not display which implies the form is not being reloaded.  I am fairly new to Zend and will appreciate any help as to how I can force a reload of a Zend form programmatically.

I have more background on the problem.  The problem is that on the second load of the web page the script files are not being found.  The script files are defined in the layout.phtml file as being in ../js/myscript.js  whereas when running the second load the chrome console shows that it is looking in admin/js/myscript.js which is the incorrect directory.  So why do the pointers to the javascript directory get changed when loading the web page the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to your js files.